# Is it possible to retrive other than the best Dirichlet components?

Tags: r, dirichlet

I run microbiota analysis with `library(DirichletMultinomial)` and fit the count data to values of k from 1 to 15. I got the best result for k = 5. You can view the plot:
[Model fit as a function of Dirichlet component number received.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAauu.png)
However I would like to subset my data for k = 7.

Is it possible to do so, and how?

Can anyone help?

Best regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the help page `?dmn` and the argument `k=`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it looks so obvious... I should have try it